# SNI Dynamic Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, dynamic, ssl-certificate, sni

I'm pulling my hair out here. 
Websites like [wix.com](http://wix.com), [squarespace.com](http://squarespace.com) ...etc; can generate websites on the fly and still use SSL on every one of the millions of custom domains.

I try to do the same thing, **but I can't figure out how they do it**!?

The logical solution would be on Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            <VirtualHost *:443>
                    ServerAlias *
                    UseCanonicalName Off

                    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                    SSLEngine on
                    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/%0/server.crt
                    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/%0/server.key
            </VirtualHost></IfModule>
```

But when I restart apache I get an error: **SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/ssl/%0/server.crt' does not exist or is empty**

Even when I create a dummy folder /ssl/%0/ with some dummy certificates... it still used the (wrong) dummy certificates.

I know some will get on their high horses and yell that you cannot resolve the server name BEFORE the TLS handshake.
But according to this [post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apache-module-mod-vhost-alias-le/9476/8) and other ones: %0 can be resolved with [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) because the server name is sent with SNI...

I know this works: a second approach would be to create a virtualhost for every custom domain:

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
                    ServerName site111.ca
                    ServerAlias www.site111.ca

                    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                    SSLEngine on
                    SSLCertificateFile "/var/app/s3/ssl/site111.ca/certificate.crt"
                    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/app/s3/ssl/site111.ca/certificate.key"
                    SSLCertificateChainFile "/var/app/s3/ssl/site111.ca/certificate.chain"
            </VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName site222.ca
         ServerAlias www.site222.ca
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html

      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile "/var/app/s3/ssl/site222.ca/certificate.crt"
      SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/app/s3/ssl/site222.ca/certificate.key"
      SSLCertificateChainFile "/var/app/s3/ssl/site222.ca/certificate.chain"
```

I could create a dirty system where I add one virtual host per new domain and reload apache every day Eeewwww... and again: Apache cap the number of virtual hosts to 256 :/

How do they do it!? Is there other technology that can help me? Nginx, Nodejs?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you think this needs to be part of the static server configuration? You can create a configuration which matches a wildcard and then use for example HTTP_HOST in your application to decide which kind of resources to serve. Also, what makes you think that they use a different certificate for each of the sites instead of just a wildcard certificate?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer @SteffenUllrich. Can you please expand on your idea? I don't understand. The HTTPS needs to be resolved before being accessed by the app, so what you do mean by: " You can create a configuration which matches a wildcard and then use for example HTTP_HOST in your application"? Also, I can make: site111.mysite.com work no problem, but I try to make site111.com, site222.com work. Maybe we talk past each other :)

Comment: It only works when you can use a wildcard certificate, i.e. \*.mysite.com is possible but \*.com not. But that's also not what the other site offer, don't they?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Actually that's exactly what they provide. If you have site111.com, site222.com say Wix will host these domains in addition to site111.wix.com and site222.wix.com which is easy to do. I'm looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: uwsgi with python provide a platform for what I want... is there an alternative? 
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SNI.html#massive-sni-hosting

Comment: I try to understand what you're saying... You say that I can do "TLS Termination" in PHP with OpenSSL?

I configure Apache to passthrough HTTPS request and terminate the request in my code? Is that correct?

Comment: I did not talk about TLS termination in PHP. The web server still terminates the TLS but from `HTTP_HOST` you can see which site the request was for inside PHP and thus serve the site-specific content.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to do the same thing, but I can't figure out how they do it!?

To generate SSL websites on the fly, they use Letsencrypt certificate authority as you can check yourself (example : CN = www.thefoodmarketchiswick.com). But for the websites hosted under .wix.com names, they're just using a wildcard certicate ( CN = *.wix.com ) . Till then, easy.

The second question, as you mentioned Apache could not handle this massive hosting (and no one believes you could host millions of applications on one single server). Have a look on this [Netcraft Survey](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2017/05/25/may-2017-web-server-survey.html) which gives some clues. I can't answer for them, but running an openssl s_client ends in error, meaning they aren't doing very compliant things.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: they use wildcard certificates. So the problem is solved @ the certificate level and at the server config level, not only at the server config level like you are trying to do.

Couple of points:

- `The logical solution` - hardly do I see anything "logical" in Computer Science or Software Engineering. It's engineering, not math, you have to DO stuff, not THINK stuff up. So knowledge becomes more important than intelligence in a lot of cases (not all).
- You have a correct point about SNI - it is a push-back of host identification meachanism to the TCP/SSL layer (prior to HTTP where HTTP headers become available).
- `virtualhost for every custom domain` - Depending on the scale we are talking about, it could work. However, if you onboard a client with 200, 1000, 5000 - subdomains. What then?
- `How do they do it` - Let me just provide examples: HTTP proxy like cloudflare generates a free certificate for you, that you have to add on your server (PROXY->ORIGIN ecryption) and END_USER -> CLOUDFLARE connection is encrypted using a wildcard certificate. These are the DNS names of the wildcard certificate they issued for me:

Abbreviated:

```
DNS Name=sni178747.cloudflaressl.com
DNS Name=*.9992924.com
DNS Name=*.apum.de
DNS Name=*.arbomedia.net
DNS Name=*.australiacasinobonus.net
DNS Name=*.auto-lpg.de
DNS Name=*.autoprof.de
DNS Name=*.circuitodesafio.com.br
DNS Name=*.data--center.info
DNS Name=*.devclub.com
DNS Name=*.eissportanlagen.de
DNS Name=*.entrepreneur-hebdo.fr
DNS Name=*.environmentalbrasil.com.br
DNS Name=*.gofitnessplan.fr
DNS Name=*.golfinterieur.info
DNS Name=*.greenbuch.cf
DNS Name=*.mindaugas.cf
DNS Name=*.mp3fdm.trade
DNS Name=*.mp3freedom.info
DNS Name=*.mp3star.cricket
DNS Name=environmentalbrasil.com.br
DNS Name=gofitnessplan.fr
DNS Name=golfinterieur.info
DNS Name=greenbuch.cf
DNS Name=mindaugas.cf
DNS Name=mp3fdm.trade
DNS Name=mp3freedom.info
DNS Name=mp3star.cricket
DNS Name=preussische-geschichte.de
```

- How does the configuration of such server look? It is really a server farm, under a loadbalancer, w/ resources shareded (static resources on separately tuned machines w/ cache). There are multiple virtual hosts / domains / host aliases on each of the server, but only 1 SSL file for many of them (or all, depending on the scale). The domains can have dedicated configurations, they can be grouped together if their configurations are identical.
- Regarding webserver recommendations - unless there is a good reason to use APACHE, I would not use it. There is a reason why nginx is gaining traction and popularity.